# OpenSSL version not changed after downgrading from 1.0.2g to 1.0.1

Tags: ssl

I'm using ubuntu version of `0.16.04.2` with PHP version of `7.0.33`.
Now I'm having trouble connecting on my database which is located on another server. On my code the error says `TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746` and I tried to search on this. And the cause of error says is on my Openssl version which is `1.0.2g` that I needed to downgrade to `1.0.1`. I tried to downgrade my ssl version using:

`wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/7531893/+files/openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31_amd64.deb`

AND

`sudo dpkg -i openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31_amd64.deb`

then checking my ssl version says:

`OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012 (Library: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016)`

Still my ssl version is `1.0.2g` on my `phpinfo`

[image]

Comment: Please provide the output of `echo $PATH`,  `which openssl`, and `whereis openssl`.

Comment: Please check your release of Ubuntu.  The current updates for 16.04 LTS should put you at 16.04.6, so you're 16.04.2 could mean you haven't updated since before 5-Aug-2017 (release date of 16.04.3)   Depending on where you got your release info from, it could be your machine is insecure, or that you only told us what you originally installed with.  (*your PHP release looks old too - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=php)

Comment: @earthmeLon  you mean information of openssl on the phpinfo?

Comment: This might install a new openssl version but it does not automatically re-link all dependent applications against the new openssl version, i.e. they still use the same libraries. But it is in most cases a bad idea to downgrade to an old and unsupported version of OpenSSL anyway. It is likely that your problem can be fixed instead with the current version - only in this case it would be necessary to know about your actual problem and not only about your attempts to fix it.